# How to split a list of tuples based on the minimum value in each tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

Let's say I have a list of tuples (to make it easy I will just put 6 values in the example) like so:

```
x = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (0,10,100), (4,0,5), (2,1,3), (3.3,9,1.2), (4.5,2,0), (2,4,10), (100, 10, 30)]
```

The list `x` is a list of tuples, each tuple has 3 values so only 3 indexes.

What I want is to split the list `x` into 3 lists, the first list has the minimum value in the tuple at the first index, the second list has the minimum value in the tuple at the second index, the 3rd list has the minimum value of the tuple at the 3rd index. Basically, I need to enter each tuple see where the minimum value is (at which index) and the put the tuple in the sub-list in which it belongs.

So I would have as result:

```
x1 = [(1,2,3), (0,10,100), (2,4,10)]
x2 = [(4,0,5), (2,1,3), (100, 10, 30)]
x3 = [(2,3,1), (3.3,9,1.2), (4.5,2,0)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension with simple check could give you desired output:

```
x = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (0,10,100), (4,0,5), (2,1,3), (3.3,9,1.2), (4.5,2,0), (2,4,10), (100, 10, 30)]

x1 = [i for i in x if i[0] == min(i)]
x2 = [i for i in x if i[1] == min(i)]
x3 = [i for i in x if i[2] == min(i)]
```

Comment: wont this be O(3*n) i.e we need to loop over the entire list 3 times?

Comment: @CutePoison `O(3*n) == O(n)`

Comment: Of course, but you still need to loop over the list 3 times (that was my point by the "pseudeo" O)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just do it in a loop:

```py
import numpy as np
x = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (0,10,100), (4,0,5), (2,1,3), (3.3,9,1.2), (4.5,2,0), (2,4,10), (100, 10, 30)]
Xs = {0:[],1:[],2:[]} #For indexing 


for t in x:
    idx = np.argmin(t)
    Xs[idx].append(t)

x1 = Xs[0]
x2 = Xs[1]
x3 = Xs[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

def argmin(arr):
    return min(range(len(arr)), key=lambda x: arr[x])

for t in x:
    d[argmin(t)].append(t)
```

Or using `numpy.argmin`:

```
for i, t in zip(np.argmin(x, 1), x):
    d[i].append(t)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {0: [(1, 2, 3), (0, 10, 100), (2, 4, 10)],
             2: [(2, 3, 1), (3.3, 9, 1.2), (4.5, 2, 0)],
             1: [(4, 0, 5), (2, 1, 3), (100, 10, 30)]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using list comprehension:

```
abc = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (0,10,100), (4,0,5), (2,1,3), (3.3,9,1.2), (4.5,2,0), (2,4,10), (100, 10, 30)]


x1 = [x for x in abc if x.index(min(x))==0]
x2 = [x for x in abc if x.index(min(x))==1]
x3 = [x for x in abc if x.index(min(x))==2]

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(x3)

Output:
[(1, 2, 3), (0, 10, 100), (2, 4, 10)]
[(4, 0, 5), (2, 1, 3), (100, 10, 30)]
[(2, 3, 1), (3.3, 9, 1.2), (4.5, 2, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def meth(a):
    if a[0] < a[1] and a[0] < a[2]:
        return 1
    if a[0] > a[1] and a[0] < a[2]:
        return 0
    return -1
x = sorted(x, key=meth)
print(x[:3])
print(x[3:6])
print(x[6:9])
```

Comment: This gives the wrong result if `x = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1)]` for example (and basically for any other list size that is different from the one in the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with no imports and a single pass on the input list.

- Initialize the result list with three empty sublists.
- Pass over each tuple, and append it to the sublist in the matching index of the minimum element in the tuple.
- In the end, each sublist will contain the tuples whose minimum element is in the same index as the sublist:

```py
x = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (0,10,100), (4,0,5), (2,1,3), (3.3,9,1.2), (4.5,2,0), (2,4,10), (100, 10, 30)]

mins = [[], [], []]
for tup in x:
    mins[tup.index(min(tup))].append(tup)

print(mins)
```

Will give:

```
[[(1, 2, 3), (0, 10, 100), (2, 4, 10)],    # mins[0] - tuples with minimum in index 0
 [(4, 0, 5), (2, 1, 3), (100, 10, 30)],    # mins[1] - tuples with minimum in index 1
 [(2, 3, 1), (3.3, 9, 1.2), (4.5, 2, 0)]]  # mins[2] - tuples with minimum in index 2
```